# non square matrices multiplication

Tags: c++, openmp

This code doesn't work except for squared matrices like `a[4][4]`, `b[4][4]`, `result2[4][4]` but it didn't work for `a[4][10]`, `b[10][10]`, `result2[4][10]`

```
//Init
for(r=0;r<numrowsa;r++){
    for(c=0;c<numcolsa;c++){
        a[r][c]=rand()%101;
    }
}

for(r=0;r<numrowsb;r++){
    for(c=0;c<numcolsb;c++){
        b[r][c]=rand()%101;
    }
}
for(r=0;r<numrowsr;r++){
    for(c=0;c<numcolsr;c++){
        result[r][c]=0;
    }
}
for(r=0;r<numrowsr2;r++){
    for(c=0;c<numcolr2;c++){
        result2[r][c]=0;
    }
}
//end init
t1=clock();

//trying parallel calculation
# pragma omp parallel num_threads(4) private(j)
{
    int thr = omp_get_thread_num();

    if(thr == 0)
        for(c=0;c<numcolsr;c++){
            for(j=0 ;j<numcolsa ; j++)
                result[0][c]+=a[0][j]*b[j][c];
        }
    else if (thr ==1 )
        for(c=0;c<numcolsr;c++){
            for(j=0 ; j<numcolsa ; j++)
                result[1][c]+=a[1][j]*b[j][c];
        }
    else if (thr ==2 )
        for(c=0;c<numcolsr;c++){
            for(j=0 ; j<numcolsa ; j++)
                result[2][c]+=a[2][j]*b[j][c];
        }
    else if (thr ==3)
        for(c=0;c<numcolsr;c++){
            for(j=0 ; j<numcolsa ; j++)
                result[3][c]+=a[3][j]*b[j][c];
        }
}
t2=clock();
cout <<endl<< "Time"<<t2-t1<<"ms"<<endl;

t1 = clock();
//trying serial calculation 
for(r=0;r<numrowsr2;r++){
    for(c=0;c<numcolr2;c++){
        for(i=0 ; i<numcolsa ; i++)
            result2[r][c]+=a[r][i]*b[i][c];
    }
}
t2 = clock();

/*
for(r=0;r<numrows;r++){
    for(c=0;c<numcols;c++){
        cout <<result[r][c]<<" ";
        if(c == numcols-1)
            cout << endl;
    }
}
*/
cout <<endl<< "Time"<<t2-t1<<"ms"<<endl;
```

The error is

> Runtime check failure Stack around variable `'b'` was is corrupted

What's the problem?

Comment: even when you can get it to work it will probably be slower than the single threaded version

Comment: You're accessing memory outside of the bounds of array `b`.

Comment: a[i][j] are the demensions of the array? If so, check that you are doing a valid multiplication.

Comment: @Ahmed - I don't know, however, that's the meaning of the error message you're receiving.

Comment: The **MOST** important part of any (C++) program are the types. I see not a single type in the above code description as a result it is practically imposable to help. *Type information* please. Secondly these things are hard enough to diagnose, why not give us something we can compile and test. You will probably get a lot more help.

Comment: the type doesn't matter .. assume all matrices are ints.

Comment: @Ahmed The *sizes* of the array do matter. And if you know so well what matters and what not, why do you ask us why your program doesn't work?

Comment: The code style hurts my eyes. I hope you are not taught this style at school.

Comment: Sjored you are so constructive

Answer (score 1):

ouch.

```
# pragma omp parallel
int t = omp_get_thread_num();
int nt = ...;
for(int i=t ; i<M ; i += nt) {
  for(int j=0 ; j<N ; ++j) {
    for(int k=0 ; k<K ; ++k) {
        .... 
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

```
if(thr == 0)
    for(c=0;c<numcolsr;c++){
        for(j=0 ;j<numcolsa ; j++)
            result[0][c]+=a[0][j]*b[j][c];
    }
 else if (thr ==1 )
    for(c=0;c<numcolsr;c++){
        for(j=0 ; j<numcolsa ; j++)
            result[1][c]+=a[1][j]*b[j][c];
    } 
 // and so on
```

I don't know the details of omp, but am I correct in thinking that `c` and `j` will be *shared* among the threads? Because all loops use the same `c` and the same `j`.

In that case, various **race conditions** could happen. E.g. thread 1 could execute `c++` just before thread 0 would execute `result[0][c]+=a[0][j]*b[j][c]`, with an out-of-bounds read/write as result.